# how to write variadic function for any number of string concatenation in c++

Tags: c++, string-concatenation, variadic

I am a newbie in c++. I know this is a very common question, but I want a complete code to concat any number of strings which are passed to function in c++. I am calling the function as:

```
string var1,var2;
var1=concat_string("one","two");
cout<<var1<<endl;
var2=concat_string("one","two","three");
cout<<var2<<endl;
```

My required output is:

```
onetwo
onetwothree
```

I have read about variadic function, but I tried the following code to concatenate strings without worrying of the result size and number of string arguments. My code is:

```
#include <cstdarg>
template<typename... T>
string concat_string(T const&... t){
    std::stringstream s;
    s<<t;
    return s;
}
```

But I got lots of error in this code. How can I correct my code. Thanks..

Comment: you can simply do `std::string("one")+"two"+"three";` I dont think this is a common question, because you dont need such a function...Is this an exercise?

Comment: @tobi303 Thank you for a simple and nice solution. It works fine. But actually I just wanted to learn variadic function procedure for string concatenation, so that I can apply this procedure in some other application.

Answer (score 8):

In C++17, with fold expression, it would be

```
template<typename... Ts>
string concat_string(Ts const&... ts){
    std::stringstream s;
    (s << ... << ts);
    return s.str();
}
```

Previously (but since C++11), you have to rely on some trick to have a valid expansion context, such as:

```
template<typename... Ts>
string concat_string(Ts const&... ts){
    std::stringstream s;
    int dummy[] = {0, ((s << ts), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    return s.str();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have used the correct fold expression syntax? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: @Zingam: indeed, C++17 version fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like you're learning C++11, here's a minor extension of @Jarod42's excellent solution to support [perfect forwarding](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/):

```
template <typename... T>
std::string concat_string(T&&... ts) {
  std::stringstream s;
  int dummy[] = { 0, ((s << std::forward<T>(ts)), 0)... };
  static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
  return s.str();
}
```

Perfect forwarding and rvalue references is another feature in C++11 that can result in improved performance.